# Unable to create App in ItunesConnect for beta testing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have registered as Apple Developer by enrolling in Apple Developer Program, still I am unable to see my Apps in ItunesConnect and unable to create new App. On Apple Developer Site it is Showing as Apple Developer but on ItunesConnect it is again saying for enrolment for apple developer program.
Kindly Let me know how make apple developer account used in Both Apple developer site and on iTunesConnect and how to create app on ItunesConnect.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How long has it been since you created your dev account? Maybe you didn't let the servers update.

Comment: I  have activated apple developer account three days before on 26-06-2015. I have done activation through activation Link, its showed activation successful. I have been trying since then to log in to itunesconnect, When i click on apps it redirects me to [link] (https://www.apple.com/itunes/working-itunes/sell-content/apps/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid apple developer account you should be able to log in with it in itunes connect. Then you simply navigate to the apps and create a new app. Before that however you should create a provisioning profile for the app and set its Bundle identifier, since itunes connect uses that.

Comment: Yes. This is the right way and I am having valid apple developer account. But There is no option like add apps inside Apps Tab. It again giving option of enrolment for apple developer program. I have made contact to Apple support Team. What should the next step for me?

Comment: @Ashish Shende if you are receiving a prompt to enroll in the program that means that apple have not validated your account. Just wait to see what the support team will say.

Comment: I have done activation through activation Link, its showed activation successful. And on developer.apple.com it is showing valid Developer Account, I am using is successfully for my project. Also I have made contact with Apple support team.

Comment: Problem solved. ItunesConnect Account activation done successfully. I got mail from apple to activate it. I think, I should waited.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. ItunesConnect Account activation done successfully. I got mail from apple to activate it. I think, I should waited.